# Finding and removing ._ files with batch file

Tags: macos, file, batch-file, command-line

I'm trying to find and remove `._` files using a batch file. The files were copied from a Mac onto a PC.

```
ECHO Again!
DIR /B /A-D /ON /S ._* 2>nul
DEL /S ._*
```

It will list them but won't delete them. What's up with that?

```
D:\projects\._my_colours.txt
D:\projects\._png_vs_jpeg.jsx
D:\projects\._rainbow_screen_sizes.jsx
D:\projects\._save_it_mac.jsx
D:\projects\._some_text.txt
Could Not Find D:\projects\*._
```

I can delete them by hand, however, I just want to know where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files carried over from MAC should have the archive and hidden properties only, so to ensure that you only pick those up, I'd suggest that you only select those for deletion. The `DEL` command has an `/A` option which selects the files to delete based upon their attributes. As soon as you use the `/A` option it picks up all attributes as if you'd selected them. If you do not exclude any attributes using the `-` prefix it will delete them all, *(except for Read-only, unless you've included the `/F` option too)*. For example `DEL /F /A ._*` will delete those with `R`ead-only, `S`ystem, `H`idden, `A`rchive, un`I`ndexed and reparse points (`L`). In this case your wanting those with just `H` and `A`, so to exclude all others you should use their exclusion prefix. Additionally as `._*` is a global wildcard, you'll probably want to use the `/Q` option to prevent a prompted request for confirmation.

```bat
Del /S /Q /A:HA-R-S-I-L ._*
```

As a note-worthy point, if you have MAC directories transferred over too, those may have file partners. For example the ready for archiving hidden directory `.Trashes` will be partnered with a ready for archiving hidden file named `._.Trashes` along side it. These would be deleted using the wildcard above, so if you have those type of directories, and you're not removing those too, you may wish to use a different method in order to preserve their partner files.

You could do that from the [command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line) via a [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop). *(From a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) you need to escape the `%` characters with another, `%%`*):

```bat
For /F "Delims=" %A In ('Dir /B /S /A:HA-D-R-S-I-L ._* 2^>NUL') Do @If Not Exist "%~dpxA\" Del /A "%A"
```

In this case, the `DIR` command selects all of the files using the same methodology as the `DEL` command used, and passes those files as metavariables to the `Do` portion. We then delete each passed file, as long as it isn't a partner to a directory. We can do that using the `/A` option alone, *because `DIR` has preselected only those we want*. To perform the check for a partner, we just use a simple `IF NOT EXIST` statement, remembering that when checking for the existence of a directory, we use a trailing backslash. The check is performed by expanding each metavariable, `%A` to its `drive:`, `\path\` and `.extension` using `%~dpxA`. The expansion of `D:\MyDirectory\SubDirectory\._.Trashes` would return `D:\MyDirectory\SubDirectory\.Trashes` so the check performed will effectively be `If Not Exist "D:\MyDirectory\SubDirectory\.Trashes\"`. If that directory does not exist then it is deleted using `Del /A "D:\MyDirectory\SubDirectory\._.Trashes"`.

Answer (score 0):

System files! D'oh!

```
DEL /AH /S ._*
```

Comment: @Compo If you wanna put that as an answer, I'll take it :)

Comment: Please note that I deleted the comment and posted it in an answer, in extended format, as requested. It has now been six days, is there a reason why you have not accepted it?

Comment: But it's all sorted now :) Answer: I'm lazy, I'm not on Stack Overflow all the time, and I do have a learning differential with a reading sped of a dead turtle.